# Webform2pdf and CiviCRM fields: pdf empty

Tags: webforms, civicrm

I have a Drupal website with CiviCRM. I created a webform and installed webform2pdf to create a pdf and CiviCRM integration module to add CiviCRM fields to my webform. After submission the webform fields are correctly added to the pdf but the CiviCRM fields are not.

Any idea? You think you could fix it or give me any advise?

Comment: Any error messages in the logs?

Comment: Hi hashkey, You might be interested to know that there is an effort to create a CiviCRM stackexchange site. If you could go to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm and click to 'commit' supporting the initiative that would be great. Secondly, we need more people with 200 reputation on another Stack Exchange site like Drupal Answers. So if you could ask or especially answer questions then you may be able to help us get to the 100 people we need for that. I think we only need 6 more.

Answer (score 0):

In a Webform, CiviCRM fields *are* webform fields. There is no difference as far as Drupal is concerned. The only exception is CiviCRM credit card fields (which you really don't want to store in the webform submission).
The "existing contact" field is another special case, but although it gets processed a bit differently it is still a "real" webform field and ought to work fine.
So aside from the above I can think of no reason why any CiviCRM-related fields would not appear on a PDF.